# Media Gallery – Gear menu unavailable

Tags: media

I created a Media Gallery on my Drupal 7 site and I am using views to output the teaser of all my galleries. Everything works as expected, but the gear menu is missing, that enables the user to delete images from the gallery. [The documentation page describes this menu](http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/feature/media-gallery/media):

[image: Gear menu]
[image: Gear menu]

Does anybody has an idea what to do?

Comment: Do you have the core contextual links module enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the Contextual links module enabled. That could be doing it, or if Contextual links is enabled check that you have permission for your account.

This may be related: https://drupal.org/node/1450840

Also check if Views UI enabled. (if needed, may not be relevant)